# the use of relative pronoun "which"

Tags: relative-pronouns

The sentence below is from a journal.

> In the first research
>   study using the four categories it was found that the
>   construct’s content validity and the **instrument assessing
>   it** were valid.

My question is , can the bolded part "instrument assessing it" be rewritten into:

1) instrument which were used to assess it
2) instrument which assessed it
3) instrument which were assessing it

Do they all still remain grammatical and convey the same meaning?

And in all three cases, is it correct to assume the relative pronoun "which" represents "instrument"?

Comment: Have you considered "instrument which was assessing it"?

Comment: @BillJ Thank you, I didn't consider that one when posting this question, i will add that into it.

Comment: The sentence from the journal is better than yours with changes. In any case, it would be plural: which were used to assess them. The singular would refer to any singular antecedent.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you, I have changed it to plural. But why is the sentence from the journal better ?

Comment: It is better because any sentence where a relative pronoun + verb can be reduced is more elegant. The car which was sitting in the driveway was dirty.= The car sitting in the driveway was dirty. Fewer words, less bulky. :)